# Power optimization in Linux

Tags: linux

I am working on a traffic surveillance project which performs various image processing tasks with a number of visual sensors and a computing platform. My basic task in the project is the power optimization/management. I am using a ZOTAC-IONITX computing platform (Intel ATOM CPU + NVIDIA ION GPU). The problems that I am currently facing are:

I am unable to model the power consumption of various components e.g., processor, GPU, hard drive, memory etc, since there seems to be no way to measure the power consumption of individual system components. Since I don't have a power consumption model, I cannot come up with a power optimization algorithm. I am currently working on Linux.

I would really appreciate any suggestions in this regard.

Comment: You'll probably get more answers on http://serverfault.com

Comment: You care about power, so why are you using x86 exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ACPI](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) is designed to handle not only full system suspend/wakeup, but should work on a per-device base too. This should help you with testing the effect on overall system power consumption.

But first look at general recommendations for power management like [this one for Gentoo](http://docs.huihoo.com/gentoo/resources/document-listing/power-management-guide.html) and try the generic solutions, that others have done before.

You may already get what you want. After all ACPI is often referred to as complicated, and [finding not much about selective suspend](http://ecosia.org/search.php?q=acpi+selective+suspend+components&addon=opensearch) other than for USB (external) devices most likely indicates, it is not a great, or at least not an easy way to go. Depending on your expertise (in hardware and Gnu/Linux) you could still succeed, since a Linux OS tends to operate close to the hardware and is a powerful base for tricky computing operations in general.

But as Ben Voight said before, x86 is in general not the preferred platform for power-efficient applications, and you should better look for alternatives, if this is allowed inside your project task at all.

Comment: Well, in my application, computing performance is a major metric as well as the energy consumption. The board that I currently use is the least power consuming board with a CUDA-enable GPU (good for parallel operations). Embedded platforms do have even less energy consumption, but unfortunately no embedded platform has the CUDA-enable GPU so far. That's why we selected this platform. What, in your suggestion, could be a better computing platform that can easily allow the power measurements of individual system components (and of course is energy efficient as well).

Comment: You're building at the edge of embedded computing, as you obviously recognized yourself. But I was able to find a family of rugged products by GE Intelligent Platforms[1], based around the NVIDIA® CUDA™ architecture. As this is marked military grade equipment I'm not sure, if this is publicly available and reasonably priced, still it does exist. Follow the general approach to control power consumption for Linux systems (see my link in the answer above). [1]http://defense.ge-ip.com/products/2077

Answer (score 0):

Can you measure total power input under various controlled conditions? Simulate the variables you can manage such as disk drive operation?

Comment: That's a very crude approach...

Comment: I can measure the total power consumed by the whole board, but not by the individual components. I can calculate the power consumed by a certain application just by calculating the difference between the idle and full-workload power consumption (which is of course not a good case). I want to know and control the power modes (and power consumption) of individual system components, e.g., processor, GPU, memory, hard drive, network card.